# Maintain Aspect Ratio in a Silverlight Image

Tags: silverlight, image, windows-phone-7

Ok .. so here's the scenario. I've got a WP7 silverlight app, that loads an image from the net. Now, these images will be taken from mobile devices, so they may be in portrait or landscape mode. Certainly not a square.

Is there any way to maintain the aspect ratio when I show these in a silverlight `<Image>` control?

I'm ok with either of two resolutions:

- That the image shows up in its correct aspect ratio within a predefined box that I've defined in xaml
- Or that the image is cropped into the square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way silverlight was built, you can set the width OR the height on the image, it will automatically max out whatever property you set and calculates the other side of the image so that it keeps the aspect-ratio.

So, just set a width on the image and center or right,left,top,bottom align it. (do not stretch it).

Comment: hah, that was easy :-P I'm so used to always having to handle this, that it didn't occur to me that it would be the default behavior. Thanks!