# Resize Image and retaining aspect ratio

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am loading an image using the the PhotoChooserTask on Windows Phone 7. After loading the photo, I want to be able to immediately resize the photo whilst keeping it aspect ratio and this is without displaying the image in the UI, then save the to the IsolatedStorage.

So far, I have something like this:

```
    private void SaveToIsolatedStorage(Stream imageStream, string fileName)
    {
        using (var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName))
            {
                var wbBarcodeImage = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100);
                wbBarcodeImage.SetSource(imageStream);
                wbBarcodeImage.Resize(100, 100, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.NearestNeighbor);
                wbBarcodeImage.SaveJpeg(fileStream, 100, 100, 0, 85);
            }
        }
    }
```

It's resizing the image, but I am unable to figure out how to keep the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maintain Aspect Ratio in a Silverlight Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768661/maintain-aspect-ratio-in-a-silverlight-image)

Comment: The guy is asking how to maintain the aspect ratio whilst diplaying the image in the <image> control though. I need a way to resize whilst maintaining it aspect ratio without displaying the image.

Comment: Ah. Sorry my misunderstanding. However there will be other questions that answer that question - it's not a problem unique to Silverlight - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942866/resize-image-while-maintaining-aspect-ratio for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the image properties for height and width and determine aspect ration. If you then know either height or width, you can calculate the other value. Your need to add querying these properties to your code and then a little math.

Comment: I would love to work out the aspect ratio, if only there is a way to access the exif data of the original image. Currently there doesn't seem to be a way to do so, and I can't load the image with BitmapImage because it resize images bigger than 2000px.

Comment: I'll mark this as answered because your answer has all allowed me to query into why BitmapImage wasn't retrieving the actual pixels height and width. It was a bug in Mango SDk Beta2.